# Finding the symbolic root of a non-linear function with fractional exponents

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

Define $f(x, a, t) = (x-t)^a - \frac{x^2}{2}$ where $x>0$ is the main variable of interest and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is the parameter of curvature:

```
f[x_, a_, t_] := (x - t)^a - x^2/2
```

I want to find the symbolic solution for $x^*$ that maximizes this function. I can do so for $t=0$ by solving the first derivative:

```
Solve[D[f[x, a, 0], x] == 0, x]
```

which yields $x \rightarrow a^{\frac{1}{2-a}} $.

However, $t$ can take any real value. I can plot and see there is in fact a solution:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[D[f[x, a, t], x]], {x, 0, 2}], {{a, 0.5}, 0.01, 0.99}, {{t, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image: manipulate_plot]

Thus, I try to find the root when $t$ is set to any nonzero value. For example, for $t=1$, `Solve[]` produces an error:

```
Solve[D[f[x, a, 1], x] == 0, x]
```

[image: solve_out]

As per the suggestion, I use `Reduce[]`:

```
Reduce[D[f[x, a, 1], x] == 0, x]
```

But this seems to run indefinitely. Is there a symbolic closed-form solution $x^*$ as a function of $a$? If so, how can I find it?

Comment: I think there is only a solution `a=ProductLog[x (-t + x) Log[-t + x]]/Log[-t + x]` in symbolic form!

Comment: This: `x==-t*FoxH[{{{1, -1}, {2, -1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, (1 + 1/(-2 + a))}}}, {{{1, 
     1/(-2 + a)}}, {}}, -a^((1/(-2 + a)))*t]` formula gives only **one** root. Only for: `0<a<1` and `t>0`.